# Visual form builder Is this plugin compatible with Amazon S3/Cloudfront?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, formbuilder

I am using vusual form builder for one of my WordPress site. Visual form builder this plugin compatible with Amazon S3/Cloudfront? The upload function is storing the files on our S3 server correctly but the link to the file in the "Entries" section is pointing to a local path rather than our Cloudfront path and therefore it's a broken link.
Even the email received by the user also has the uploaded file link with local path rather than cloudfront. How it can be fixed.

In the form entries, the file uploaded path should be actual cloudfront URL and the email received by the user also have the actual path of the file in the email content.

Comment: You should probably start by contacting the developer of the plugin regarding this issue.